# Como buscar em uma String o X e substituir por um número e utilizar o mesmo para calcular?

Tags: c, c++

Estou criando um programa em C para fazer o método de Newtow-Raphson, ele deverá calcular automáticamente para a pessoa. Porém em uma parte do método deverá ser feito a substituição automatica de valores na função como por exemplo abaixo:

> f(x) = x^3 - 3x -1
>
> f(1) = 1^3 - 3.1 -1

A função o usuário digitará como uma String, e o programa deve pegar essa string substituir o número no X e usar como um calculo. Existe alguma função pronta para isto? Estou parado nesta parte, até agora eu tenho :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

void painelPerguntas();
double calculoQtIteracao(double raizA, double raizB, double testeParada);
double calculoModuloAB(double raizA, double raizB);

int main(){
    painelPerguntas();

}

void painelPerguntas(){
    double raizA = 0, raizB = 0, testeParada = 0;
    printf("RAIZ [a]: ");
    scanf("%lf", &raizA);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("RAIZ [B]: ");
    scanf("%lf", &raizB);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("PARADA: ");
    scanf("%lf", &testeParada);

    //CALCULO QUANTIDADE DE ITERAÇÕES
    calculoQtIteracao(raizA, raizB, testeParada);
    double qtIteracoes = calculoQtIteracao(raizA, raizB, testeParada);

    //CALCULA |A-B|
    calculoModuloAB(raizA, raizB);

    //CALCULA F(A).F(C)


}

double calculoQtIteracao(double raizA, double raizB, double testeParada){
    double calculo = (log10(raizB - raizA) - log10(testeParada)) / log10(2);
    return round(calculo);
}

double calculoModuloAB(double raizA, double raizB){
    double calculo = raizA - raizB;
    if(calculo < 0){
        calculo = calculo * -1;
        return calculo;
    }else {
        return calculo;
    }
}

double calculoSinal(double a, double c){
    double calculoA =
}
```

Comment: A função `calculoSinal()` que é responsável por calcular a função matemática `f(x) = x^3 - 3x -1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a intenção é substituir `x` na string por um valor, isso se resolve facilmente com um laço:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    if (s[i] == 'x') s[i] = numero;
}
```

O único problema é que os sinais de multiplicação deveriam ser explícitos pelo usuário (ex: `f(x) = x^3 - 3*x -1`), senão ficaria mais complicado (teria que aumentar o tamanho da string, movê-la e etc).

Agora, se desejar também calcular a expressão, então não há um jeito simples por si só sem recorrer a bastante código. Uma solução é usar [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr), que aparentemente faz o trabalho pesado que você precisa.

Comment: Sim o usário digitaria no OUTPUT a função como você digitou assim por exemplo: x^3 - 3*x -1, entendi o que você fez a cima, mas e agora como usar essa expressão já com o número substituido para calcular e retornar o resultado?

Comment: Essa parte não é algo trivial. Se você puder usar bibliotecas externas, uma solução é a TinyExpr que te passei.

Comment: Ata, então só existe bibliotecas externas, e nenhuma "padrão" para utilizar né @Emoon? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer localizar um numero em uma string correto?!
Você pode usar a função find da string.

```
int AcharValor(std::string srt)
{
    if (srt.find('0') != std::string::npos)
        return 0;
    else if (srt.find('1') != std::string::npos)
        return 1;
    else if (srt.find('2') != std::string::npos)
        return 2;
    else if (srt.find('3') != std::string::npos)
        return 3;
    else if (srt.find('4') != std::string::npos)
        return 4;
    else if (srt.find('5') != std::string::npos)
        return 5;
    else if (srt.find('6') != std::string::npos)
        return 6;
    else if (srt.find('7') != std::string::npos)
        return 7;
    else if (srt.find('8') != std::string::npos)
        return 8;
    else if (srt.find('9') != std::string::npos)
        return 9;
}
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642292/function-to-check-if-string-contains-a-number

Comment: Eu quero localizar o X em uma String e depois usar essa String como expressão para calcular, e estou fazendo em C e não em C++.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer duas coisas diferentes ao mesmo tempo: substituição de texto em string (que basta olhar a boost.org, que tem excelentes funções para isso) e transformar o "código fonte" de uma equação em comandos. Essa segunda parte é mais complicada pois o problema real é um problema da área de compiladores - dado um código fonte, gerar um conjunto de instruções de computador. Você tem que procurar por algo que compile esse texto para uma sequência de instruções.

Se você não quiser de dar ao trabalho de fazer (ou encontrar pronto) um mini compilador de equações você poderia usar algum dos processamentos em GPU, tipo CUDA ou OpenCL ou Compute Shaders. Eles aceitam strings como código fonte para rodar na GPU, embora não da forma como você está fazendo.